# How to Save a Trapezoidally Formed Paragraph as a Trapezoidal Image

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, crop

I have produced a trapezoidally-shaped paragraph of words as follows.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalefnt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

```
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\parshape 16 % The number after \parshape is a count of the number of lines.
0pt 0.73\linewidth
.015\textwidth \dimexpr0.70\textwidth
.03\textwidth \dimexpr0.67\textwidth
.045\textwidth \dimexpr0.64\textwidth
.06\textwidth \dimexpr0.61\textwidth
.075\textwidth \dimexpr0.58\textwidth
.09\textwidth \dimexpr0.55\textwidth
.105\textwidth \dimexpr0.52\textwidth
.12\textwidth \dimexpr0.49\textwidth
.135\textwidth \dimexpr0.46\textwidth
.15\textwidth \dimexpr0.43\textwidth
.165\textwidth \dimexpr0.40\textwidth
.18\textwidth \dimexpr0.37\textwidth
.195\textwidth \dimexpr0.34\textwidth
.21\textwidth \dimexpr0.31\textwidth
.225\textwidth \dimexpr0.28\textwidth
\hskip 95pt {\large{\scalefont{0.85}\textbf{A Title.} \\ \lipsum[4].}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

What I need to do now is to somehow save it as a trapezoidal shape with minimal whitespace for later inclusion someplace else.

If I save it as some type of a picture, it is then saved as a rectangle with lots of unwanted white space near the bottom of the trapezoid---and I only know how to crop it in a rectangular fashion.

QUESTION: Is it possible to either save the paragraph in a trapezoidal shape; or, in a rectangular shape that can be cropped as a trapezoid? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean with 'later inclusion someplace else'? Do you want to include the paragraph in your LaTeX documents? Or in another type of document, like a web page or a drawing program? And what do you want to put in the empty space in the lower corners, other text, or a background image or color or something? Depending on the use case it may be sufficient to save it as a `.png` image with white as transparent color, that or more or less functionally equivalent to cropping.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for there, but maybe creating a trapezoidal shape into a `tikzpicture` and include your image or paragraph into it...